# Can't "Save" WiFi Connection

Tags: networking, wireless

### My organization provides the information below for accessing the open network, but will not provide technical support. When I fill all the fields, the [Save] button is grayed out. Anyone have any insights? I've connected in the past, with the same settings I thought . . .

Settings

- Network Name - xxxx
- Security Type - WPA2-Enterprise
- Encryption Type - AES
- Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048) - checked
- Select Authentication Method - EAP-MSCHAP v2
- Automatically use my Windows logon name - Unchecked
- Specify authentication mode - Checked
- Enable Fast Reconnect - Checked
- Anonymous Identity - Leave Blank
- Security - 802.1x EAP
- Identity - guestID
- Key (Passphrase) - password
- Validate Server Certificate - Checked

TIA

Ron

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1929229

Answer (score 0):

Try working through all of the tabs on the Wifi config control. If any options are red, it won't save. I found this on the password field for WPA2, where I just typed in 10 random characters. After this the Save button re-enabled.

Comment: I admit I don't understand what you are trying to say with your first sentence.